# Is this sentence grammatically incorrect?

Tags: prepositions

> Tears escape my fingers and drip into the bottle, with the salt mixing with the water.

I know the sentence would flow better without the first
"with" but would it still be grammatically correct in the above phrasing?

Comment: The second “with” is fine and leaving it out imparts a meaning as if the salt mixes the water with something else, as if it be the salt that is steering, if you will. The key is that “to mix” is an ergative verb.

Comment: Did you mean to suggest the omission of the FIRST "with"?

Comment: Yes, I meant the first "with." Sorry, I just edited it.

Comment: Omitting the first "with" looks fine to me.

Comment: You could also use a semicolon after bottle and delete the first "with." At least, I think that would be fine. But I agree that deleting the first "with" looks fine (and poetic).

Comment: Would the sentence flow if I left the first "with"? In other words, would it still be considered grammatically correct?